# discord py create_guild did not return

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to use discord py 2.0.0 to create a guild and give me the invite URL.

However, when he executes to

```py
guild = await self.bot.create_guild(name="My server")
```

he will not execute the following codes

```py
async def create(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

    await interaction.response.send_message("a")

    guild = await self.bot.create_guild(name="My server")
    await interaction.response.send_message("b") 

    inv = await guild.text_channels[0].create_invite()

    await interaction.response.send_message(inv.url)
```

Then when I additionally execute the program below, he lists that server.

Sorry my English is not well.

I want some way can create a guild and it's invite url in a command.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working this morning. The issue is that the guild object returned from `bot.create_guild` won't necessarily have the channels cached - you gotta fetch them. And then, the first "channel" in the list of channels is a category - so we want to filter them for actual text channels.

Code is slightly different to yours as I was quick prototyping; you can adapt for your needs accordingly.

```py
@client.slash_command()
async def create(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    new_guild = await client.create_guild(name="A test Guild")  # type: discord.Guild
    actual_guild = await client.fetch_guild(new_guild.id)
    channels = await actual_guild.fetch_channels()
    channel = [c for c in channels if type(c) == discord.TextChannel][0]  # type: discord.TextChannel
    invite = await channel.create_invite()
    print(invite.url)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Invite: {invite.url}")
```

Working fine as below.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear
`await interaction.response.send_message("a")

    guild = await self.bot.create_guild(name="My server")
    await interaction.response.send_message("b") `
It will only answer me a and not b
The code after `guild = await self.bot.create_guild(name="My server")` will not run to

Comment: Yes, sending B won't work as you've already used the response object. Did you try the code I've provided?